# What is the source of Irving Babbitt's disctinction between supernaturalism, humanism and naturalism

Tags: inspiration, lin-yutang, my-country-and-my-people, irving-babbitt

In the chapter "Ideals of Life" of *My Country and My People*, Lin Yutang writes (emphasis mine),

> The Confucian conception of man's place in nature is that "Heaven, earth and man" are regarded as "the three geniuses of the universe". This is a distinction somewhat corresponding to the **Babbittian threefold distinction of supernaturalism, humanism and naturalism**.

The rest of the paragraph goes on discussing the Confucian view on man's place in the universe; Irving Babbitt is not mentioned anywhere else in the book.

It is not immediately obvious from [Wikipedia's article on Irving Babbitt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irving_Babbitt) whether this distinction was expressed in a specific publication. The article [Irving Babbitt and Lin Yutang](https://isi.org/modern-age/irving-babbitt-and-lin-yutang/) (2014), which discusses Irving Babbitt's influence on Lin Yutang, is not helpful either. The article [Philosophy 312: Oriental Philosophy
Naturalism, Supernaturalism, and Humanism](https://philosophy.lander.edu/oriental/naturalism.html) on Lander University's Eastern Philosophy website discusses naturalism, supernaturalism and humanism without mentioning Babbitt. So what exactly was Lin Yutang's source?

Comment: Possibly Babbitt's 1919 [_Rousseau and Romanticism_](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/50235/50235-h/50235-h.htm), whose Chap IV uses these words a lot?

Comment: @kimchilover Thanks for the link. Last month, users from Germany were still blocked on Gutenberg (due to legal/copyright issues), so I hadn't seen that book yet.

Comment: Also available via the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.187936/mode/2up).